# access can't find the field '|' referred to in expression

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

i encountered the error 'microsoft office access can't find the field '|' referred to in your expression" when i using the DCount function to count the number of OrderNo occurence in a table. datatype for OrderNo is number.
here's what i've done

```
If DCount("[OrderNo]", "tblDisposition", "[OrderNo]='" & [txtOrderNo.Value] & "'") > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate data", vbOKOnly, "ERROR"
Else
    MsgBox "succeed"
End If
```

on form's load event i set the txtOrderNo control source to OrderNo in tblDisposition.
i also try to use DLookup function and it seems to be same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `[txtOrderNo.Value]` looks wrong. Try it without the square brackets, e.g:

```
If DCount("[OrderNo]", "tblDisposition", "[OrderNo]=" & txtOrderNo.Value) > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate data", vbOKOnly, "ERROR"
Else
    MsgBox "succeed"
End If
```

Comment: already tried that. it give 'data type mismatch in criteria expression'.

Comment: In that case try removing the enclosing single quotes as well, as per my amended answer.